# Zend Framework 2, form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I'm trying to create a form for editing. 
Сontroller:

```
$someValue = $this->someMapper->someMethod()
(someMethod returns Hydrator object)

$form->bind($someValue);
```

But it`s not working. Values are not added to Form. 
If I add to Controller this:

```
$form->setData($this->someMapper->extract($someValue);
```

That is all to the form normally added. I do not understand what the problem is.

Hydrator Object:

> object(Admin\Entity\Article)#331 (13) { ["id":protected]=> string(2)
>   "16" ["heading":protected]=> string(85) "fsdgsdgsdgsdg"
>   ["subHeading":protected]=> string(3) "fdddgdgdg"
>   ["imgDescription":protected]=> string(4) "jghj" ["text":protected]=>
>   string(15) " ghjghj
>
> " ["category":protected]=> string(4) "category"
>   ["commentation":protected]=> string(1) "0" ["importance":protected]=>
>   string(1) "0" ["path":protected]=> string(48) "fgdfgdgdg-fgdfhwt-gf"
>   ["comments":protected]=> NULL ["views":protected]=> NULL
>   ["date":protected]=> string(19) "2016-06-06 11:23:05"
>   ["img":protected]=> string(11) "1492546.jpg" }

View.phtml

```
<?php
 $form = $this->form;

 $form->prepare();

 $form->get('submit')->setValue('Update Post');

 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

 echo $this->formCollection($form);

 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Comment: You need bind an object to form, not a hydrator.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#binding-an-object

Comment: I read, but do not understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object `Entity` with properties like this:

```
<?php
class Article
{
    private $id; /* $_POST['id] */
    private $headline; /* $_POST['headline']*/
    private $author; /* $_POST['author']*/
    private $comments; /* $_POST['comments']*/
}
```

Properties in this object must be equal with POST variables. And you can bind this entity to a form and set a hydrator.

Or you can use an object `ArrayObject` instead `Entity`.

```
$request = $this->getRequest(); /* An request object in Controller */

$form->bind(new Article()); /* bind entity */
// $form->bind(new ArrayObject()); /* or bind ArrayObject */
$form->setHydrator(new ObjectProperty()); /* Add a data to properties of an Entity */
$form->setData($request->getPost()); /* Set a POST data to form */
```

After validation you can get `Entity` with valid data from a form.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $entity = $form->getObject(); /* Entity or ArrayObject */
}
```

Comment: So I can add data, for example in the base. I need to extract data from the database and transfer them to the form for editing

Comment: Ok, I understand. Try to add a hydrator to a form. $form->setHydrator(new ObjectProperty());